# Is there a way to conditional format both row and column based on another cell?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditional format both row and column based on the data in C2.

For example, if C2=1 then I want Row 1 and Column G to be highlighted because G contains "X". I know how to conditional format for the horizontal data (=$B5=$C$2), but is there a way to highlight the vertical data?

[image: Data]

Comment: What's the logic exactly? What would happen if you change `C2` to `2`... should columns B and N be highlighted?

Comment: Yes, if I change C2 to 2 then I would want Row 2 and Columns B and N to be highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

[image]

Select cells C5 to U20 and then create a conditional format using this formula:

```
=OR($B5=$C$2,INDEX($C$5:$U$20,$C$2,COLUMN()-2)="x")
```

[image]